# Django - is there better way to get data from forms field?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

Is there a better way(easiest and safest) to retreive data from input fields that has been created in form.Form than `request.POST.get()`?

For practice purpose I have 2 pages:

1. I enter some data
2. I use data from 1st page

this is my solution:

```
form.py:
class DataForm(forms.Form):
    login = forms.CharField(label='login')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean_data(self):
        login = self.request.POST.get('login')
        return login
```

---

```
views.py:
class MyTestView(FormView):
    template_name = 'template.html'
    form_class = DataForm
    success_url = '/finaldestination/'

    def form_valid(self,form):
        form.clean_data()
        return super().form_valid(form)

def testFunction(request):
    print('Welcome here')
    testprint()
    form = DataForm(request.POST or None)
    testFunction.login = request.POST.get('login')
    testFunction.password = request.POST.get('password') 
    importedScript.login(testFunction.login, testFunction.password)

    tested()
    print(form.Login)
    return render(request, 'finaldestination.html')

def tested():
    x = testFunction.login
    print(x, ', is a really cool guy')
```

---

```
template.html:
TEST:
<form action="/finaldestination/" method="post" name='btn'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.login }}
    {{ form.password }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

`ImportedScript.bot` is a simple code to login to Instagram.
My solution is working but I have heard that it is not a safest way to retreive data. As I wrote at the beginning it is for practice purpose because I still do not understand how to use the data entered by the user.

For example I would like to create a loan calculator where user has to put a lot of data(all on one page) like earnings, date of birth, length of the loan, etc and then how connect his inputs with my functions()

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely definitely completely not be doing any of this. It is unsafe for several reasons.

Firstly, the point of a form is that you call its `is_valid()` method and then access the data via `cleaned_data`.

Secondly, never store data between requests like this. It will be visible to all users; so the next user to go to `tested` will see the data you sent. Normally I would recommend using the session to store data between requests, but that is not the right thing to do either because you should be using Django's built-in authentication framework; doing so would then give you access to the logged-in user via `request.user`.

Finally, note that your form's `clean_data` method is pointless and will never be called. But again, within that method you would access `self.cleaned_data`; there would be no such thing as `self.request` there.